# If statement returns true though only one of several conditions are met (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I want to notify users answering a form if any of the optional radio buttons are left unanswered before submitting (as to ensure that they've been skipped intentionally).
My problem is that although I'm setting up an if-statement with several conditions the if-statement returns true when any one of the conditions is met instead of when all of them are met. I'm using jQuery 1.7.1.

Javascript:

```
$("#optmsg").show();
function updateFormEnabledOpt() {
if (verifyOpt()) {
    $("#optmsg").hide();
} else {
    $("#optmsg").show();
}
}

function verifyOpt() {
if ($("#formidable input:radio[name='q11']:checked").val() !== 'undefined' && $("#formidable input:radio[name='q12']:checked").val() !== 'undefined' && $("#formidable input:radio[name='q13']:checked").val() !== 'undefined') {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

$('#formidable input:radio[name="q11"]').change(updateFormEnabledOpt);
$('#formidable input:radio[name="q12"]').change(updateFormEnabledOpt);
$('#formidable input:radio[name="q13"]').change(updateFormEnabledOpt);​
```

So: As soon as any of the three questions has a checked radio button #optmsg gets hidden.
Jsfiddle (with some html to go with the script): http://jsfiddle.net/rnPA6/

UPDATE: Thanks for the help! With blazing speed I might add! Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rnPA6/14/

Comment: What a **mess**!!! **225** Characters in one line?!

Comment: Haha yeah, jsFiddle's TidyUp removed the line breaks (+ they made jsLint give validation errors anyway). Agreed prettier with line breaks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val()` method returns and empty string if nothing is set in the input element which is not equal to `undefined` due to which if condition was passing through. Try this which will not pass if the value is empty.

```
if ($("#formidable input:radio[name='q11']:checked").val() 
     && $("#formidable input:radio[name='q12']:checked").val() 
     && $("#formidable input:radio[name='q13']:checked").val() ) {

}
```

When no value is set for a input radio button jQuery returns `"on"` when you call `val()` method on it. So you should set atleast a empty value to each of the radio button if not set.

Comment: Why did you "break" that lovely one line to three? **:)**

Comment: This worked beautifully! (even though jslint reported bad line breaks)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing using and(&&). In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rnPA6/3/) jsfiddle, I fixed your code to use or(||).

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing against the string containing the text `'undefined'` and not the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
function updateFormEnabledOpt() {
  $("#optmsg").show();
  if (($("#formidable input:radio[name='q11']:checked").val() !== undefined) && ($("#formidable input:radio[name='q12']:checked").val() !== undefined) && ($("#formidable input:radio[name='q13']:checked").val() !== undefined)) {
      $("#optmsg").hide();
  } 
}

$('#formidable input:radio[name="q11"]').change(updateFormEnabledOpt);
$('#formidable input:radio[name="q12"]').change(updateFormEnabledOpt);
$('#formidable input:radio[name="q13"]').change(updateFormEnabledOpt);
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/BwUWp/

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for your help, already implemented ShankarSangoli's solution but this helped me understand why my code didn't work!